# Python: save a page with a lot of graphics as a .html file

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib, urlopen

I want to save a visited page on disk as a file. I am using a urllib and URLOpener. 
I choose a site http://emma-watson.net/. The file is saved correctly as .html, but when I open the file I noticed that the main picture on top which contains bookmarks to other subpages is not displayed and also some other elements (like POTD). How can I save the page correctly to have all of the page saved on disk?

```
def saveUrl(url):
        testfile = urllib.URLopener()
        testfile.retrieve(url,"file.html")
...
saveUrl("http://emma-watson.net")
```

The screen of real page:
[image]
The screen of the opened file on my disk:
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to save everything in a single "web archive" file, or just save all the other files alongside the .html file?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using `urllib` instead of `urllib2`, or that you're building an explicit `URLOpener` and not doing anything custom with it instead of just calling `urlopen`?

Comment: @abarnert I just decided to use urllib. And I also use URLOpener because I read that it is good. And I want to save the page on disk to have possibility to open it (the saved version), and there is no difference for me if I will save it as web archive or .html, while I can open it

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is create a very simple web scraper (that is, you want to find all the links in the file, and download them, but you don't want to do so recursively, or do any fancy filtering or postprocessing, etc.).

You could do this by using a full-on web scraper library like [`scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) and just restricting it to a depth of 1 and not enabling anything else.

Or you could do it manually. Pick your favorite HTML parser (`BeautifulSoup` is easy to use; `html.parser` is built into the stdlib; there are dozens of other choices). Download the page, then parse the resulting file, scan it for `img`, `a`, `script`, etc. tags with URLs, then download those URLs as well, and you're done.

If you want this all to be stored in a single file, there are a number of "web archive file" formats that exist, and different browsers (and other tools) support different ones. The basic idea of most of them is that you create a zipfile with the files in some specific layout and some extension like .webarch instead of .zip. That part's easy. But you also need to change all the absolute links to be relative links, which is a little harder. Still, it's not *that* hard with a tool like `BeautifulSoup` or `html.parser` or `lxml`.

---

As a side note, if you're not actually using the `UrlOpener` for anything, you're making life harder for yourself for no good reason; just use [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen). Also, as the docs mention, you should be using `urllib2`, not `urllib`; in fact `urllib.urlopen` is deprecated as of 2.6. And, even if you do need to use an explicit opener, as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#url-opener-objects) say, "Unless you need to support opening objects using schemes other than http:, ftp:, or file:, you probably want to use `FancyURLopener`."

---

Here's a simple example (enough to get you started, once you decide exactly what you do and don't want) using BeautifulSoup:

```
import os
import urllib2
import urlparse
import bs4

def saveUrl(url):
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    with open("file.html", "wb") as f:
        f.write(page)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f)
    for img in soup('img'):
        imgurl = img['src']
        imgpath = urlparse.urlparse(imgurl).path
        imgpath = 'file.html_files/' + imgpath
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(imgpath))
        img = urllib2.urlopen(imgurl)
        with open(imgpath, "wb") as f:
            f.write(img)

saveUrl("http://emma-watson.net")
```

---

This code won't work if there are any images with relative links. To handle that, you need to call [`urlparse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) to attach a base URL. And, since the base URL can be set in various different ways, if you want to handle every page anyone will ever write, you will need to read up on the documentation and write the appropriate code. It's at this point that you should start looking at something like `scrapy`. But, if you just want to handle a few sites, just writing something that works for those sites is fine.

---

Meanwhile, if any of the images are loaded by JavaScript after page-load time—which is pretty common on modern websites—nothing will work, short of actually running that JavaScript code. At that point, you probably want a browser automation tool like Selenium or a browser simulator tool like Mechanize+PhantomJS, not a scraper.

Comment: @Rop, Stackoverflow isn't for free development, it's for assistance. Just debug the "for img" loop. It will probably list all the image URL's.